# Copy from cell if two other cells meet criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, input

any help with this would be appreciated.

I am trying to copy a cell from column (G) into another worksheet, if cells from the same row in column (R) = "Y" and column (B) = "Month"

I had it working for just "Y" criteria but as soon as I added the "Month" this button has stopped working?

this is the code I have;

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Savings Q4")
        LR = .Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            With .Range("R" & i)
                If .Value = "Y" Then
            With .Range("B" & i)
                If .Value = "January" Then
                    Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("G:G").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cifas Loadings").Range("A:A")
              End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With


End Sub
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is badly written. You should just write `If .Range("R" & i).Value = "Y" And .Range("B" & i).Value = "January" Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Too Much 'Withing' and 'Ifing'

### Rules

> - The number of `With` statements must be equal to the number of `End With` statements.
> - The number of `If` statements must be equal to the number of `End If`    statements, except when there is a **'one-line' If Statement**.

### Insights

[Alexey C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10627624/alexey-c)'s solution gets those `With`-s and `If`-s in line, but problems still remain.

When you write `With .Range("R" & i)` it refers to `Sheets("Savings Q4")` from the previous `With` statement and you are actually shortening the line

```
With Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("R" & i)
```

which is **OK**.

When you later write `With .Range("B" & i)` it doesn't refer to `Sheets("Savings Q4")`, it refers to `.Range("R" & i)` i.e. your not shortening the line `With Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("B" & i)` but

```
With Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("R" & i).Range("B" & i)
```

which is **WRONG**.

[Matteo NNZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111149/matteo-nnz) correctly commented that the `If` statements could be shortened to one `If` statement  using the `And` operator.

When you write

```
Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("G:G").Copy_
    Destination:=Sheets("Cifas Loadings").Range("A:A")
```

you are copying the entire `G` column to the entire `A` column. Since this is in a loop (`For i = 1 to LR`), each time the code 'encounters' "**January**" and "**Yes**", it copies the **entire** column. It is highly unlikely that you are trying to achieve that functionality.

### Plan of Changes

> - Get rid of the 'inner' `With`'s.
> - Reduce the `If`'s using `And`.
> - Change the **COLUMN** ranges `G:G` and `A:A` to the corresponding **CELL** ranges.
> - Get rid of `Destination:=`.

### The Code

```
Sub WithIf()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Savings Q4")
        LR = .Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            If .Range("R" & i).Value = "Y" And _
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "January" Then
                .Range("G" & i).Copy Sheets("Cifas Loadings").Range("A" & i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

### Remaining Issues

A further problem might be that you didn't want the `A` column data copied in the same row as the `G` column data. If this is the case you should apply the same `LR = .Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` logic and integrate it into the code referring to the `A` column of sheet "Cifas Loadings".

Comment: Thank you for your response! it worked!! very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least, you forgot one End With and one End If. But anyway it's not correct with logical part.

```
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Savings Q4")
        LR = .Range("R" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            With .Range("R" & i)
                If .Value = "Y" Then
                    With .Range("B" & i)
                        If .Value = "January" Then
                            Sheets("Savings Q4").Range("G:G").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cifas Loadings").Range("A:A")
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
```

It's easier to make it w/o With, like

```
if Range("R"& i).value="Y" and Range("B" & i).value = "Month"
     COPE CELLS
end if
```